# How to center collection view cell when user swipes but not enough to show the other cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am trying to recreate the iOS Gallery App, where the user has two collection view controllers, the first one showing all the available images and the second one is displayed when the user taps in an image (a cell) and that same image is shown in another collection view controller with the following function:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: self.customIndexPath, at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }
}
```

where the custom indexPath is set when the user selects an item in the previous collection view controller.

The problem is, in the second collection view controller (Where the image is displayed individually), I don't know how to make it so when the user swipes right or left, the next/previous image is shown and centred, just as if the above function has been called on that image.

I've tried to call the above func in the following code

```
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let newIndexPath = IndexPath(item: indexPath.item, section: 0)
    print("Item at \(indexPath.item)")
    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: newIndexPath, at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

But its called too soon, the image is replaced by the next image as soon as the user starts going forward or backwards the collection view, I would prefer if the next image is displayed and centred when the user swiped or at least moved horizontally and more than half of the previous image isn't shown and more than half of the next image is shown, the user releases and automatically the next image is centred

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var customIndexPath = IndexPath()

let images:[UIImage] = [

    UIImage(named: "image_1")!,
    UIImage(named: "image_2")!,
    UIImage(named: "image_3")!,
    UIImage(named: "image_4")!,
    UIImage(named: "image_5")!,
    UIImage(named: "image_6")!,
    UIImage(named: "image_7")!,
    UIImage(named: "image_8")!,


]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    print(customIndexPath)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: self.customIndexPath, at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }
}


}


extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return images.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.userImageView.image = images[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let newIndexPath = IndexPath(item: indexPath.item, section: 0)
    print("Item at \(indexPath.item)")
    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: newIndexPath, at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}





}
```

The result should be very similar to the iOS Gallery App in a very basic level, when the user swipes, the next image must be shown and centred, not floating around like it is now or showed partially, also if the user swipes slowly and the next cell (next image) is not shown by at least half of its content, then the collection view must display and centre the previous image, just like the iOS Gallery App

My project until now can be found in the following link:

https://github.com/francisc112/Gallery-Test

Thanks in Advance, if there is any tutorial where I can learn to do this, please point it out.

Answer (score 0):

i just tried solving this problem using a bit different approach. Im only using the `scrollViewWillEndDragging` and `scrollViewDidEndDragging` methods. Also im using a `previousCollectionViewContentOffsetX` property which is used to tell if we should scroll to the next or prior cell when the dragging end in case the user make a fast scroll (which is a PhotosApp behaviour).

Finally i've just set a fast deceleration rate to emulate the pagination feature:

`collectionView.decelerationRate = .fast`

You can see this solution [in the pull request i've just made in your repo](https://github.com/francisc112/Gallery-Test/pull/1).

Another simpler solution is to set collectionView's min spacing for cells and lines to zero and enable the collectionView's pagination. We lose the margins between photos shown by the PhotosApp but avoid touching the scrollview delegates. I can make a pull request with this solution if you want.

Comment: why don't you piut some code? the doesn't work